# How to disable only scrolling or dragging on mapsforge

Tags: android, mapsforge

Basically, my app will function a bit like Pokemon Go. I'm using mapsforge and offline maps. At the moment the app allows auto rotate(fine), tapping(fine) and map movement, like dragging or scrolling(not sure which event does that).

I just need the app to not allow dragging/scrolling of the map. Everything else should be allowed.

Any insight would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a view on the top of your map.
That View can handle all touch events and do not give it to the map.